# Update JAR used by Android app in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, refresh

My app uses an API from an external JAR file. This JAR file has been added into my project and added in the build path. My project builds and runs just fine, but now I need to update the JAR file (some code in those classes has changed). I created a new JAR and copied it into my project after removing the old one. Do I need to "re-import" the JAR file or is there some way for Eclipse to refresh/re-examine the JAR file Im removed and re-added ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to right click on the package name in the Package Explorer and select "Refresh" and then force Eclipse to recompile everything by clicking on the "Project" menu and click on the "Clean..." option.  This works for me whenever I update JAR files in any of my Eclipse projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported a Jar, that means the file has been copied to your project directory.
If you have copied again the new Jar in your project, a simple refresh (<kbd>F5</kbd>) on the project should be enough to reference that new Jar.

No reimport needed: You could use the reimport process to copy the new Jar in your project, but it looks like you have already done it manually.