# Android 1.6 SDK - Internal File Path Issue

Tags: java, android

I am trying to read a csv file from assets/file.csv, but the log keeps spitting out that it doesn't exist.  Is my path correct for internal file storage?  This is the class file:

```
package com.xxx.view;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ReadList {

    public String[][] mainMenuList() throws IOException {

        String [][] arrayList = new String [24][24];

        File file = new File("/data/data/com.xxx.view/file.csv");

        BufferedReader bufRdr  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;

        while((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null && row < 24) { 

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line,",");

            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

                arrayList[row][col] = st.nextToken();
                col++;

            }

            col = 0;
            row++;

        }

        return arrayList;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't let you access files on the phone's storage that way.  You can only access files on the SD card via a traditional java File interface.  Check out the `AssetManager` [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) for more information.  Also, check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364185/android-read-a-gzip-file-in-the-assets-folder) for a similar example.